# How to handle duplicates created by LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, left-join

**LEFT TABLE:**

```
+------+---------+--------+
| Name | Surname | Salary |
+------+---------+--------+
| Foo  | Bar     |    100 |
| Foo  | Kar     |    300 |
| Fo   | Ba      |     35 |
+------+---------+--------+
```

**RIGHT TABLE:**

```
+------+-------+
| Name | Bonus |
+------+-------+
| Foo  |    10 |
| Foo  |    20 |
| Foo  |    50 |
| Fo   |    10 |
| Fo   |   100 |
| F    |  1000 |
+------+-------+
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| Name | Surname | Salary | Bonus |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
| Foo  | Bar     |    100 |    80 |
| Foo  | Kar     |    300 |     0 |
| Fo   | Ba      |     35 |   110 |
+------+---------+--------+-------+
```

**The closest I get is this:**

```
SELECT 
    a.Name,
    Surname,
    sum(Salary),
    sum(Bonus)
FROM (SELECT 
        Name,
        Surname,
        sum(Salary) as Salary
      FROM input
      GROUP BY 1,2) a LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name,
                                        SUM(Bonus) as Bonus
                                 FROM input2
                                 GROUP BY 1) b 
ON a.Name = b.Name
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

**Which gives:**

```
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
| Name | Surname | sum(Salary) | sum(Bonus) |
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
| Fo   | Ba      |          35 |        110 |
| Foo  | Bar     |         100 |         80 |
| Foo  | Kar     |         300 |         80 |
+------+---------+-------------+------------+
```

I can't figure out how to get rid of `Bonus` duplication. Ideal solution for me would be as specified in the 'DESIRED OUTPUT', which is adding `Bonus` to only one `Name` and for other records with the same `Name` adding `0`.

Comment: For starters, don't you need to join on both `name` and `surname` here?

Comment: right table doesnt have surname (but i agree its a poor foreign key design)

Comment: These tables are just for example, real ones I need it for are much more complex. @JacobH Yes, the problem is that I need to join just on name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Row_number over the Name category partioned by Name. This will give you different numbers for your duplicates. You can then search for the case when this number is 1 and return the result you want. Else return 0. The code can look something like this.

```
SELECT 
    a.Name,
    Surname,
    sum(Salary),
    Case    when Duplicate_Order = 1
            then bonus
            else 0
            end as 'Bonus'
FROM (SELECT 
        Name,
        Surname,
        sum(Salary) as Salary
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Name order by name) as [Duplicate_Order]
      FROM input
      GROUP BY 1,2) a 
      LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name,
                    SUM(Bonus) as Bonus
                FROM input2
                GROUP BY 1) b 
ON a.Name = b.Name
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select l.*, (case when l.seqnum = 1 then r.bonus else 0 end) as bonus
from (select l.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by salary) as seqnum
      from "left" l
     ) l left join
     (select r.name, sum(bonus) as bonus
      from "right" r
      group by r.name
     ) r
     on r.name = l.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Correlated Subquery with `sum()` aggregation to compute the bonus column, and then apply `lag()` window analytic function to get the zeros for successively identical valued column values for the `name` column :

```
select Name, Surname, Salary, 
       bonus - lag(bonus::int,1,0) over (partition by name order by salary) as bonus
from
(
select i1.*, 
       ( select sum(Bonus) 
           from input2 i2 
          where i1.Name = i2.Name 
          group by i2.Name  ) as bonus
  from input i1
) ii
order by name desc, surname;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=06017f1039672972c24895fc09f4c5d9)</kbd>